# Sequelize where issue with 6.19.1 version

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

With braking changes that sequelize introduced in new version 6.19.1

```
async findByUuid(uuid: string, options?: Omit<FindOptions<T>, 'where'>): Promise<T | null> {
  return this.model.findOne<T>({ where: { uuid }, ...options });
}
```

I am getting error for "where"

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(this: ModelStatic, options: NonNullFindOptions<Attributes>): Promise', gave the following error.
> Type '{ uuid: string; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<Attributes>'.
> Types of property 'uuid' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<Attributes[string]>'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(this: ModelStatic, options?: FindOptions<Attributes>): Promise', gave the following error.
> Type '{ uuid: string; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<Attributes>'.
> Types of property 'uuid' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<Attributes[string]>'.ts(2769)
> model.d.ts(52, 3): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'NonNullFindOptions<Attributes>'
> model.d.ts(52, 3): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'FindOptions<Attributes>'

Comment: Can you show the whole class definition?

Answer (score 0):

what I found was that there was an extra curly brackets in my *where*

```
return await AccountContact.findAll({
    where:  { whereOptions },
});
```

instead of

```
return await AccountContact.findAll({
    where:  whereOptions 
});
```